# How to get user name who updated the data from UI in MVC 5 and Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, triggers, sql-server-2012

We have a website in ASP.NET MVC 5 with Entity Framework.

When a logged in user made changes in UI (i.e. update the data) we save/update/delete the data in SQL Server as per operation performed by the user.

We also have a trigger for audit trailing.

With the trigger, table format for storing data is as below:

```
[AuditID]
[Type] -- Contains operation performed (Insert (I), Update (U), Delete (D))
[TableName]
[PK] -- Primary Key
[FieldName]
[OldValue] 
[NewValue] 
[UpdateDate] 
[UserName]
```

We are storing `SYSTEM_USER` in `[UserName]` column.

If we have any solution to store the `[UserName]` who actually made changes from UI instead of `system_user`?

Do we have any approach to pass `[UserName]` from application (UI) to the trigger?

Please share your thoughts.

I have one solution - to add `UpdatedBy` column name in all the tables so that trigger can easily get the value of `UpdatedBy` column from magic tables or from main tables.

Please suggest best approach.

Below is the trigger used.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [ids].[tr_AuditEmploee] 
ON Employee 
FOR INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS
    DECLARE @bit INT,
            @field INT,
            @maxfield INT,
            @char INT,
            @fieldname VARCHAR(128),
            @TableName VARCHAR(128),
            @PKCols VARCHAR(1000),
            @sql VARCHAR(2000), 
            @UpdateDate VARCHAR(21),
            @UserName VARCHAR(128),
            @Type CHAR(1),
            @PKSelect VARCHAR(1000)

    --You will need to change @TableName to match the table to be audited
    SELECT @TableName = 'Employee'

    -- date and user
    SELECT         
        @UserName = SYSTEM_USER,
        @UpdateDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112) + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), GETDATE(), 114)

    -- Action
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM inserted)
       IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM deleted)
          SELECT @Type = 'U'
       ELSE
          SELECT @Type = 'I'
    ELSE
       SELECT @Type = 'D'

    -- get list of columns
    SELECT * INTO #ins FROM inserted
    SELECT * INTO #del FROM deleted

    -- Get primary key columns for full outer join
    SELECT 
        @PKCols = COALESCE(@PKCols + ' and', ' on') 
               + ' i.' + c.COLUMN_NAME + ' = d.' + c.COLUMN_NAME
    FROM    
        INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS pk,
        INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE c
    WHERE   
        pk.TABLE_NAME = @TableName
        AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
        AND c.TABLE_NAME = pk.TABLE_NAME
        AND c.CONSTRAINT_NAME = pk.CONSTRAINT_NAME

    -- Get primary key select for insert
    SELECT 
        @PKSelect = COALESCE(@PKSelect+'+','') 
                    + '''' + COLUMN_NAME 
                    + '=''+convert(varchar(100),
coalesce(i.' + COLUMN_NAME +', d.' + COLUMN_NAME + '))+''''' 
    FROM    
        INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS pk ,
        INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE c
    WHERE   
        pk.TABLE_NAME = @TableName
        AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
        AND c.TABLE_NAME = pk.TABLE_NAME
        AND c.CONSTRAINT_NAME = pk.CONSTRAINT_NAME

    IF @PKCols IS NULL
    BEGIN
       RAISERROR('no PK on table %s', 16, -1, @TableName)
       RETURN
    END

    SELECT         
        @field = 0, 
        @maxfield = MAX(ORDINAL_POSITION) 
    FROM 
        INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
    WHERE 
        TABLE_NAME = @TableName

    WHILE @field < @maxfield
    BEGIN
        SELECT @field = MIN(ORDINAL_POSITION) 
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
        WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TableName 
          AND ORDINAL_POSITION > @field

        SELECT @bit = (@field - 1 )% 8 + 1
        SELECT @bit = POWER(2,@bit - 1)
        SELECT @char = ((@field - 1) / 8) + 1

        IF SUBSTRING(COLUMNS_UPDATED(),@char, 1) & @bit > 0 OR @Type IN ('I','D')
        BEGIN
            SELECT @fieldname = COLUMN_NAME 
            FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
            WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TableName 
              AND ORDINAL_POSITION = @field

            SELECT @sql = '
insert [audit].[AuditEmployee] (       Type, 
               TableName, 
               PK, 
               FieldName, 
               OldValue, 
               NewValue, 
               UpdateDate, 
               UserName)
select ''' + @Type + ''',''' 
       + @TableName + ''',' + @PKSelect
       + ',''' + @fieldname + ''''
       + ',convert(varchar(1000),d.' + @fieldname + ')'
       + ',convert(varchar(1000),i.' + @fieldname + ')'
       + ',''' + @UpdateDate + ''''
       + ',''' + @UserName + ''''
       + ' from #ins i full outer join #del d'
       + @PKCols
       + ' where i.' + @fieldname + ' <> d.' + @fieldname 
       + ' or (i.' + @fieldname + ' is null and  d.' + @fieldname + ' is not null)' 
       + ' or (i.' + @fieldname + ' is not null and  d.' + @fieldname + ' is null)' 
               EXEC (@sql)
       END
END
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Have you tried setting a session variable when the user logs in? Might be a good approach. Then you could grab the user ID back out of session and add it to the updated by column?

Comment: Currently there is no UpdatedBy column in main tables, so how will I pass the user name to trigger ?

Comment: are you using code first?

Comment: yes, code first approach